# Python matplotlib/seaborn plot bar chart subcategories

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dictionary of dictionaries called `data`. I want to plot a bar chart so that each of `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` have a value for the `pos` and `neg`.

I don't want the `pos` and `neg` bars to be stacked on top of each other. I want them side by side.

Additionally, I want the categories to be sorted by descending order of their total frequency (`pos + neg`)

```
data = {'A': {'pos': 289794, 'neg': 515063},
        'B': {'pos': 174790, 'neg': 292551},
        'C': {'pos': 375574, 'neg': 586616},
        'D': {'pos': 14932, 'neg': 8661}}
```

Comment: What's your question? Do you face any problems when doing this kind of chart?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The main issue for me is that I want each category for my bar chart to have two subcategories (`pos` and `neg`)

Comment: That would be easiest solved by `pd.DataFrame(data).T.plot.bar()` I suppose?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest this works. Can you add it as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct one. Also shouldn't `matplotlib` have an inbuilt function to do this since it seems like situations like this would be common

Comment: [This is the second example in the matplotlib gallery](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/barchart.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%matplotlib inline 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': {'pos': 289794, 'neg': 515063},
        'B': {'pos': 174790, 'neg': 292551},
        'C': {'pos': 375574, 'neg': 586616},
        'D': {'pos': 14932, 'neg': 8661}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T
df ['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df.sort_values('sum', ascending=False)[['neg','pos']].plot.bar()
```

[image]